# Magento 2.4.2-p1 issue with Elastic Search

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I am facing below issue after upgrade from Magento 2.3.5 to Magento 2.4.2-p1 version.

```
Exception #0 (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception): {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[1:234] [histogram] failed to parse field [interval]"}],"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[1:234] [histogram] failed to parse field [interval]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"[interval] must be >0 for histogram aggregation [prices]"}},"status":400}
```

How can we resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What is the elastic search version you are using?

Comment: @SukumarGorai, I am using Elastic Search 7.6

Comment: @SanjayJethva did you find any solutions related to this?

Comment: @MagentoLearner I face such issue because client has entered a price in Layered navigation Price Step and due to that such error coming to category. https://a.cl.ly/GGuWJmoA

Comment: Thank you Bhai @SanjayJethva. So solution will be? Sorry still learning this platform

Answer (score 0):

As you did not specify it, Elasticsearch will expect date value in ISO format: yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS'Z' (e.g., 2017-02-03T19:27:20.606Z)

This answer helped me to solve the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043856/failed-to-parse-timestamp-elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

in store->configuration->catalog->catalog->layered Navigation->"Default Price Navigation Step"
you need to give any value > 0 for this field and then reindex all indexes